# SQL query to add column values

Tags: sql, oracle, select

TABLE T1

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| AMAN | 10 |
| JIM | 11 |
| SAM | 12 |

TABLE T2

| VAL | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A00 | 10 |
| B0 | 11 |

The result I want:

T3

| Name | ID | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMAN | 10 | A00 |
| JIM | 11 | B0 |
| SAM | 12 | NA |

How can I write this query?

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT    t1.name, t1.id, coalesce(t2.val,'n/a')
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Those ticks should be proper single quotes.

Comment: On an iPad best I could do

Comment: Hmm, there's no possibility to enter single quotes on an iPad? Oh well, I edited it for you if you cannot do that for whatever reason.

Comment: I couldn’t see it,

Comment: @AbBennett try a long press on `’`.

Answer (score 1):

You could left join on the id:

```sql
SELECT    t1.name, t1.id, t2.val
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: It wont give 'NA' on the rows which dont have common id

Comment: @kiara A lot of tools display `null` as `NA`, so I was assuming that's what OP meant. If the requirement is to have the string literal `'NA'` instead, you're right, and this need to be explicitly handled (e.g., by using `coaleasce`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select a.Name,
a.val,
b.val, 
.
.
.
from TABLE T1 as a left join Table T2 b 
on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: I don't think so; inner join won't help here, you'll be missing some data. That's the main "problem" - you'd need **outer** join.

Comment: @Littlefoot I agree with you. Initially the question format was very different ( there were no tabular structure and value) and that's why I supposed inner join would work. Anyway thanks for pointing out this out I think Left Join is most suited , I'll edit my answer.